# Transforming Dependent Vectors into Independent Ones

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm working on a Blind Source Separation problem and I've  to characterize a transformation able to go from a set of dependent vectors to a set of independent ones, with spaces of different dimensions.  Let me properly formulate the problem.

Consider a set $$V=\{v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_N\}, \; v_i \in \mathbb{R}^{M}, \forall i$$ with $M < N$. Hence, $V$ is a Linear Dependent (LD) set.

Consider now a transformation $T$

$$T: \mathbb{R}^{M} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N}$$
and the set

$$W=\{T(v_1), T(v_2), \cdots T(v_N)\}, \; T(v_i) \in \mathbb{R}^{N}, \forall i$$

**Question:** Is it possible that $W$ is a Linear Independent (LI) set? If so, which are the characteristics of $T$ (linear, nonlinear, what about its rows/columns, rank, etc)?

In other words, I'm searching for a transformation that takes $N$ vectors from a low dimensional space to a higher dimensional one. For example, one could transform 3 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (which are necessarily LD) into a set of 3 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ (possibly LI).

Comment: This cannot be done if we are assuming $T$ is linear, as any dependency of $v_1, \ldots, v_N$ will carry over to $T(v_1), \ldots, T(v_N)$. If we dispense with linearity, then colomns/rows and rank no longer apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible because then the list $Tv_1,\dots,Tv_n$ would be linearly dependent.

Proposition: Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be a linearly independent list in $R^m$, where $n>m$. Let $T : R^m \to R^n$ be a linear map. Then the list $Tv_1,\dots,Tv_n$ is linearly dependent.

Proof: Given that $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is linearly dependent, let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be scalars not all zero such that $$a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n=0$$ Applying $T$ to both sides and using the linearity of $T$ we get $$T(a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n)=a_1Tv_1+\dots+a_nTv_n=0$$

Because not all the scalars in $a_1,\dots,a_n$ were zero, the above representation implies that the list $Tv_1,\dots,Tv_n$ is linearly dependent.

Edit: Although I proved this for the special case where $n>m$, the result holds in general. The following would be the general statement of this result.

Theorem: Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over some field $F$. Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be a linearly dependent list of vectors in $V$. Let $T : V\to W$ be a linear map. Then the list $Tv_1,\dots,Tv_n$ is linearly dependent.

Proof: The proof of this is exactly as the proof of the above proposition.